# How to invoke ModelB.create on ModelA.afterCreate()

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm trying to execute this (on 0.10.0-rc7):

User.js

```
afterCreate: function(values, next) {
    Token.create({
        hash: uuid.v4(),
        type: 'email',
        user: values.id
    }).done(function (err, token) {
            console.log(token);
            next();
        });
}
```

But I'm receiving an error:
`TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'done'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.done()` is deprecated in Waterline.  Use `.exec()` instead.